# Allocating ByteBuffer with allocate() or allocateDirect()

Tags: java, android, yuv

I am trying to fill a ByteBuffer with some data to simulating the process of stitching to YUV_420_888 image's ByteBuffer. When I allocate it with `allocate()` and put data into it like this:

```
int width = 16;
int height = 16;
int combinedSize = width * height * 3 / 2;
ByteBuffer combinedBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(combinedSize);
for(int i = 0; i < height * 3 / 2; i++) {
    int curLine =  i * width;
    for(int j = 0; j < width / 2; j++) {
        combinedBuffer.put(curLine + j, (byte) 125);
    }
}
```

which means I want to fill the left part of the Bytebuffer with fixed value 125 and do nothing to the right part, I get correct Bytebuffer, but, when I just replace `allocate` with `allocateDirect`, my data is wrong, as is shown in the picture. The left on the picture shows the data I got using `allocateDirect` and the right shows the data I got using `allocate`.
The format of it is YUV420.
[allocate() VS allocateDirect()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hewo8.jpg)
Moreover, when I use array().length to get the size of the Bytebuffer,`alloacte` method got 384 which equals 16 * 16 * 3 / 2 but `alloacteDirect` got 391 which has 7 Bytes more.

I use ByteBuffer.array() to get the data and put it into a file.
I want to know, do they have difference which can influence the data I put?

Comment: Note: Be careful with calling `array()` on a direct buffer without checking `hasArray()` first, as whether or not a direct buffer has a backing array [is unspecified](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#allocateDirect(int)).

Comment: "_I use `ByteBuffer.array()` to get the data and put it into the file_" -- What happens if you write the buffer directly (i.e., via a `WritableByteChannel`)? If you're stuck with an `OutputStream`, then note you [can adapt it to a channel](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/channels/Channels#newChannel(java.io.OutputStream)).